# function call in JavaScript from head first JS

Tags: javascript

output: Jane Doloop

i dont understand the line at Marked_Line(comment)???i guess it's a simple thing but dont understand the logic here,help ,thanks.

```
<script>
var passengers = [  { name: "Jane Doloop", paid: true, ticket: "coach" },
                    { name: "Dr. Evel", paid: true, ticket: "firstclass" },
                    { name: "Sue Property", paid: false, ticket: "firstclass" },
                    { name: "John Funcall", paid: true, ticket: "premium" } ];

function processPassengers(passengers, testfunction)
{
  for(var i=0;i<passengers.length;i++)
  {
    if(!testfunction(passengers[i]))//------------->Marked_Line 
    {          
      return false;
    }
  } 
  return true; 
}

function printPassenger(passenger) {
  console.log(passenger.name);
  return false;
}

processPassengers(passengers,printPassenger);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`testfunction` is a function which returns a boolean (`true` or `false`) value.

The negation (`!`) operator converts that to the opposite value, meaning it converts `true` to `false` and `false` to `true`.